# Can anyone help me figure out why my registration form will not submit to my database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a registration form for my mvc5 asp.net application. I cannot seem to get it to work. I am building an asp.net application with MVC5 and am using SQLExpress 2014 to build the DB I am trying to input into. I think I am not fully understanding model binding and the data access layer. When I debug it seems to step through the way I want it to but eventually the values just go back to null.

Model:

```
public class userInfo
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int userID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
        public string userName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        /*[NotMapped]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string confirmPassword { get; set; }*/
    }
```

Above is my model for userInfo. I have commented out the comparePassword attribute. I figured I will try to figure that out later. I am not sure if that attribute needs to be included in the database or not.

Next is my viewmodel for binding:

```
public DbSet<userInfo> Users { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<userInfo>().ToTable("tblusers");
    }
```

Here in my accountcontroller is where I try to retrieve the data from the form and post it to the database table:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(FormCollection userBuild)
{
    userInfoViewModel vm = new userInfoViewModel();

    userInfo user = new userInfo();
    user.firstName = Request.Form["firstName"];
    user.lastName = Request.Form["lastName"];
    user.email = Request.Form["email"];
    user.userName = Request.Form["userName"];
    user.password = Request.Form["password"];

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            userInfoDal Dal = new userInfoDal();
            Dal.Users.Add(user);
            Dal.SaveChanges();
            vm.newUser = new userInfo();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View("Register");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        vm.newUser = user;
    }
    userInfoDal dal = new userInfoDal();             
    return View("Register");
}
```

As you can see, I build a viewmodel object in order to retrieve the user input, then I build the object itself. I collect all of the user input into the object and if its valid data I try to create the data access layer connetion and add the object to it. Right around savechanges (from what I can tell) is where I run into problems (I think??).

I dont know how important this is, but here is my view for reference:

```
<h2>Registration</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>New User Registration</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.confirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.confirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>-->*@

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Then there is nothing in the viewModel except:

```
public userInfo newUser { get; set; }
```

I have been wracking my brain with this for a couple days. I am very new to MVC so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add model to your view

```
@model Yourproject.Models.userInfo
```

Comment: I have that added already. I just didnt including it in what I posted

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically I had code in there set up to fill a list and display it in a view. I removed all of that and just added the form posts to the userInfo object and then saved it to the DB. It was easy once I stepped away for a couple hours.